# Python Method Resolution Order

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

Could someone explain the output of given code and how python MRO works in this case?

```py
class A(object):
    def go(self):
        print("go A go!")


class B(A):
    def go(self):
        super(B, self).go()
        print("go B go!")


class C(A):
    def go(self):
        super(C, self).go()
        print("go C go!")


class D(C, B):
    def go(self):
        super(D, self).go()
        print("go D go!")


d = D()
d.go()
```

Output:

```
go A go!
go B go!
go C go!
go D go!
```

Following left-to-right and depth I would say it should be:

```
go A go!
go C go!
go D go!
```

but seems it dosn't work as I thought.

Comment: Might be clearer if you printed before each super call as well as after

Comment: I see but still don't get how it is possible B method is called. And even if it is, why not with another A call?

Comment: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Comment: Add those prints before each super call, then you’ll be able to see where A.go() is called from - update your question with the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MRO for a class is based on the MRO of it parents:

```
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

The [three rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) are:

1. Children go before parents:

- A < object
- B < A
- C < A
- D < C
- D < B

2. Parents go in the order of bases:

- C < B

3. Parent mros are merged, preserving their order.

- merge `B < A < object` with `C < A < object`

In the early days of Python 2, the search rule used to be depth-first-left-ot-right, but that changed based on research into the C3 linearization algorithm.

See the [Super Considered Super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) blog post for ways to take advantage of this algorithm in real code.

Comment: Thanks, it is mostly clear for me now. But still do not know why B method was called. Because it was merged with C? What happen on that merge? Both methods are called?

Comment: D's mro is DCBAObj.  That means that those classes are called in that order.  B is called because it is on the list, no other reason.